# Using slug instead of ID in URLs and getting objects hashing the slug

Tags: sql, postgresql, url, hash, hashmap

I don't know if this question sounds too stupid, but I appreciate any answer to it.

I use URL design that looks like Stackoverflow e.g.:

```
example.com/object/{ID}/{SLUG}
```

Where ID is just an integer corresponding to a serial key in my database (Postgres), the slug does nothing special actually.

What if I want to use a more modern URL design like Quora e.g.:

```
example.com/object/{SLUG}
```

And in my backend software (Django in my case) I hash the slug using some lightweight hash function (16 or 32-bit for example) and get the corresponding object using an additional column that contains the hash (in that case it will just another integer column)?
The slugs are guaranteed to be unique, and it is almost impossible to expand beyond 2^32 objects.